# I tried all the answer to solve this "Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Inventory123.WebApiApplication'." but not get success

Tags: asp.net

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Inventory123.WebApiApplication'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Inventory123.WebApiApplication" Language="C#" %>

Comment: In development mode its working fine  but when i deployed it on aws server it give this error